# How to retrieve primary key related value in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I was researched every where that primary keys , candidate keys and foreign keys. I learnt each and every keys on asp.net MVC 5 entity framework.

Then I generated my code using MVC automatic generated option on Visual studio and I was surrounded with Migrations with editing some features..But, here is the thing...

I was created another model called Auction, in order to bid an item. After that, I was initialized a product ID  and other details in my Auction model. Even after that, I was try to assign user ID "using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;"
and its worked. The thing is I want to make a relationship between Automatic generated User's Model called "IdentityModels" and "AccountViewModels". But its not worked.

```
// Here is my Auction model class' segment that I took on my Auction model


[Key]
 [Required]
 public long Id { get; internal set; }
........
//other codes are avoided
......
[Required]
public string SellerUserID { get; set; }
```

Here is my AuctionController

```
 public ActionResult ViewMyBids()
        {
            var db = new AuctionsDataContext();
            var pKey = User.Identity.GetUserId();

            // I want to pass the primary key in to the auction model and get the results to a list 
            var result = db.Auctions.Find().SellerUserID(pKey);
            ViewBag.mes = result.SellerUserID;

            return ViewMyBids();

        }
```

Even I don't know how to get the primary key's value
Let's say as an example:
there is
Employee and Department....
Employee has an ID,
Employee has EmpName,
Department has a DepartmentName,

Department wants to know a particular employee's name...
DO that so,

Department table needs a foreign key  which is related to employee ID,
within that employeeID ,it can directly assign to employee's Name which is stored in Employee table...

So, as like that I want to assign automatic generated user ID and using that ID I need to retrieve all the data that ID has....

How to do this, I know to use of foreign keys or composition keys .. But in my research I am unable to find any solution for this.

So help me to solve this..Thanks.......
pls...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ActionResult ViewMyBids()
{
    var db = new AuctionsDataContext();
    var pKey = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    // I want to pass the primary key in to the auction model and get the results to a list 
    var result = db.Auctions
        .Where(p => p.SellerUserID == pKey)
        .ToList();

    // The result is a List<Auction> so the below code won't work unless you retrieve only one item
    // ViewBag.mes = result.SellerUserID;

    return ViewMyBids();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your code make my problem solved...Thanks for helping me. :)

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as correct answer if it suits your needs.